# JAXB Marshall & Unmarshall Java complex Class

Tags: java, jaxb, javafx-8, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm working with JAXB in a Java project.

I'd like to process my data with JAXB but i have a problem with these classes.

What kind of tags and so on should I add to the fields to get marshalling and unmarshalling working?

Wrapper.class

```
@XmlElement(name="database")
public class Wrapper {

    private List <Person> persons;
    private List <Quote> quotes;

    @XmlElement(name="persons")
    public List<Person> getPersons(){
        return=this.persons;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="quotes")
    public List<Quote> getQuotes(){
        return=this.quotes;
    }    
}
```

Person.class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="person")
public class Person {

    private final StringProperty name;
    private final StringProperty telephone;
    private final StringProperty mail;
    private final ObjectProperty<LocalDate> date;
    //I have problem with this complex field:
    private final ObjectProperty<List <Job>> jobs;

    //Constructor getters and setters
    ...
}
```

Job.class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="job")
public class Job {

    private final StringProperty roleName;
    private final StringProperty id;
    //I have problem with this complex field too:
    private final ObjectProperty<List <Subrole>> subroles;


    //Constructor getters and setters
    ...
}
```

Subrole.class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="subroles")
public class SubRole {
    private final StringProperty subRoleName;
    private final ObjectProperty<List <String>> actions;

    //really don't know how to treat this
    private final ObjectProperty<List<List <Activity>>> activities;

    //Constructor getters and setters
    ...
}
```

Activity.class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="activities")
public class Activity{
    private final StringProperty activityName;
    private final FloatProperty salary;
    private final FloatProperty hours;


    //Constructor getters and setters
    ...
}
```

Comment: Firstly, what is the exact problem which you are suffering from? Secondly, why did you define all classes as root element? I guess only person should be root element.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I dont' know how to manage hierarchical complex object like this

Answer (score 0):

If you have lack of knowledge about that topic and if you are using Eclipse, I can advice you creating your own XSD(XML Schema Definiton) file according to your class hierarchy (You can try Altova XML Spy e.g.). After that, move that xsd to your project and generate JAXB classes in Eclipse automatically(Right click to xsd and you will see generate option).

It will generate your JAXB classes, thus you can inspect them and learn how to manage those type of objects.

Comment: Thanks, At moment i'm implementing manually Adapters and wrapper for Marshalling and Unmarshalling, i'll give a try after